# Post binary data to web client using c#

Tags: c#, webclient, content-type

I am working on a c# project. I have to call an external web service and post file as binary data and read its response. 
Below is my code

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
var fileData = webClient.Encoding.GetString(file);
var package = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n{3}\r\n--{0}--\r\n", boundary, filename, contentType, fileData);
var nfile = webClient.Encoding.GetBytes(package);
byte[] resp = webClient.UploadData(url, "POST", nfile);
```

I have passed content type as "application/octet-stream".
I am surely missing something but cannot figure it out.

Comment: You'd be better off using `HttpClient` rather than `WebClient`. It'll handle the fiddly bits for you.

Comment: Have you tried simply `WebClient.UploadFile`? See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Dillanm You are saying I donot need to specify content type in my code ?

Comment: @Dillanm Woah! that worked. Thanks Dilanm, sometimes we approach a task with complexity and forget that things can be simple. Thanks alot, you saved my day :)

Comment: @Neha No sorry; you'll still need to specify the content type but try using `UploadFile` in place of `UploadData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply `WebClient.UploadFile`? See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx)

(posted as answer for posterity)